# How many time has Arya actually used Needle?

Tags: game-of-thrones

During Episode 1 of Season 8, *Winterfell*, Jon Snow and Arya finally meet each other again. During this scene Jon notices that Arya has kept Needle, the sword he offered her in the first Season. When he asks Arya if she has ever used it, she just answers "once or twice."

[image: maybe more than once]

While she has killed quite a bunch of folks, she hasn't used Needle each time. For example,

> she killed the Freys with poison, not Needle

How many times has Arya actually used Needle?

---

By "using Needle," I assume Jon Snow meant "use it to kill someone," but I'm also interested in other occasions where Arya has used Needle.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Four people have met their end via Needle so far.

While Arya has caused much more destruction these are people who met their demise by being stuck with the pointy end.

**1. The Stable Boy** - This one was an accident, but she poked the stable boy in Kings Landing in the belly which killed him.

**2. Polliver** - While traveling with the Hound a brawl breaks out in a Tavern. Polliver is the one who took Needle from her in the first place and is kindly introduced to the pointy end. They just wanted to eat some f**king chickens man.

**3. Rorge** - One of the three Arya saved from the burning wagon. He ends up attacking Arya and the Hound and meets his end with another stab in the belly.

**4. The Waif** - After deciding she is not No One, she is Arya Stark of Winterfell and is going home, The Waif confronts her. The deed is done in the dark after Arya draws Needle and cuts out the candle.

**Honorable Mention** - Polliver uses Needle to kill Lommy in the Lannisters' attempt to catch Arya and Gendry.

---

### Other Instances of Needle:

1. Given Needle by Jon Snow, almost stabs him with it.
2. Has to pack it away for the trip to Kings Landing.
3. Grabs it on her way out. See #1.
4. Loses it to Polliver when they are attacked on their way North.
5. Regains it at the tavern with the Hound. See #2.
6. Practices with it numerous times in travels with the Hound.
7. Must hide it away once she enters the House of Black and White.
8. Retrieves it once she decides to leave. See #4.
9. Carries it with her ever since on her journey home. Thinks about using it when runs across Ed Shereen.
10. Most notably uses it to practice with Brienne once she is back in Winterfell.

---

### Other Killing (so far):

1. The Tickler - Not a direct kill but is killed by Jaqen on direct order from Arya.
2. Ser Armory Lorch - The second name to Jaqen.
3. A bunch of soliders - The third name(s) to Jaqen while they escape Harrenhal.
4. Frey Solider #362 - Shortly after the Red Wedding Arya and Hound run into trouble and have to dispatch four soldiers.
5. Lannister Soldier #814: Just prior to reclaiming Needle Arya kills this one in the tavern brawl.
6. Ser Meryn Trant: While in Braavos Ser Meryn picks the wrong brothel to visit and shanked repeatedly in the face by Arya.
7. Lothar Frey and "Black" Walder Rivers - Baked them into a pie and served to Walder Frey.
8. Lord Walder Frey - Slit throat after eating his kin.
9. All the Freys that matter - Poisoned wine.
10. Lord Petyr "Littlefinger" Baelish - Slit throat with Valyrian Steel dagger that was used in the attempt on Bran's life.

Comment: To be factual, Lommy also met with the pointy end of Needle, even if the one at the other end was Polliver and not Arya

Comment: @Kepotx but you only asked for the times Arya used it. Maybe i'll add an Honorable mention .

Comment: It was indeed just a note, you answered my question as I expected

Comment: Not nitpicking. If Jaqen's kills belong to Arya then Littlefinger belongs to Sansa.   Every Stark except Rickon has now killed someone.

Comment: Well, to be fair, we can only know how many people she's killed with Needle *on camera.*

Comment: She took down a pigeon in Braavos with it, too.

Comment: @KharoBangdo: If only walnuts counted, then Rickon would lead all his siblings...

Comment: Do we actually know the stable boy died?

Comment: @NateEldredge Rickon killed himself by running in a straight line

Comment: Did Arya use Needle to kill the two Frey men she later cooked into a meat pie for Lord Walder Frey?

Comment: Are soldier numbers arbitrary in this post, or did they actually have those in the credits or something?

Answer (score 15):

Arya has killed a bunch of people but using Needle she has killed only 4 so far.

1. The stable boy (a stab in the gut when she is escaping  from Lannister soldiers in Kings Landing
2. <s>Unnamed Lanister soldier (a stab in the gut when she's with the Hound & they encounter Lannister men in a diner & fight breaks out over chickens)</s>  She does it with a sword & then picks up Needle. Added in other list.
3. Polliver (a stab in the throat when same as 2)
4. Rorge (a stab through the heart when he & another guy attacks Hound for collecting the bounty placed by Lannister)
5. The Waif (we actually don't see it as she slashes the candle in half in that secluded room)

Other men Arya kills without Needle

1. Unnamed Frey soldier (multiple stabbings with a knife. After the Red wedding, when Arya & Hound find them shit-talking the Stark massacre, she steals a knife from Hound)
2. Unnamed Lanister soldier (a stab in the gut when she's with the Hound & they encounter Lannister men in a diner & fight breaks out over chickens)
3. Meryn Trant (slashing throat with a knife in a brothel)
4. Lothar & Black Walder (killed & cooked into a pie)
5. Walder Frey (slashing his throat with a knife as he's eating Frey pies)
6. Frey bannerman (using poisoned wine)
7. Littlefinger (slashing his throat with the dagger he gives Bran, at his trial)
8. Unnamed little girl (although technically giving a gift of death using the water from the well in The House of Black & White, rather than killing)